# R sf Polygon multiply x coordinate by 2

Tags: r, coordinates, sf

My aim is to multiply all x coordinates by 2 and all y coordinates by 3 of an R sf object. How can I achieve this?

When running the following code the polygons are duplicated:

```
library(sf)

# Create Polygon: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html
p1 <- rbind(c(1000,1000), c(1000,2000), c(2000,2000), c(1000,1000)) 
p2 <- rbind(c(500,500), c(500,100), c(1000,1000), c(500,500)) 
pol <-st_polygon(list(p1, p2)) 
pol_geom = st_sfc(pol, crs = 4326)

# Trying to multiply x coordinate by 2 and y coordinates by 3
pol_geom_new <- st_geometry(pol_geom) * c(2,3)
st_bbox(pol_geom)
st_bbox(pol_geom_new)
pol_geom; pol_geom_new
```

Comment: Please note that assigning an arbitrary CRS can cause you considerable issues down the road. These are obviously not WGS84 decimal degree coordinates but that is the EPSG code projection that you are assigning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily modify an sf object using a matrix instead of a numeric vector, whether something you've built directly or loaded from a geopackage or shapefile. The only difference is you have to declare the scale or transform factor **as** a matrix .

```
# Using your example but not assigning WGS84
p1 <- rbind(c(1000,1000), c(1000,2000), c(2000,2000), c(1000,1000)) 
p2 <- rbind(c(500,500), c(500,100), c(1000,1000), c(500,500)) 
pol <-st_polygon(list(p1, p2)) 
pol_geom = st_sfc(pol)
st_coordinates(pol_geom)

        X    Y L1 L2
[1,] 1000 1000  1  1
[2,] 1000 2000  1  1
[3,] 2000 2000  1  1
[4,] 1000 1000  1  1
[5,]  500  500  2  1
[6,]  500  100  2  1
[7,] 1000 1000  2  1
[8,]  500  500  2  1
```

Scaling by x and y coords by multiplying a matrix (which scales X and Y), and checking the resulting coordinates:

```
pol_geom2 <- pol_geom * matrix(data = c(2,3), ncol = 2)
st_coordinates(pol_geom2)
        X    Y L1 L2
[1,] 2000 3000  1  1
[2,] 2000 6000  1  1
[3,] 4000 6000  1  1
[4,] 2000 3000  1  1
[5,] 1000 1500  2  1
[6,] 1000  300  2  1
[7,] 2000 3000  2  1
[8,] 1000 1500  2  1
```

Likewise if you wanted to shift the coordinates:

```
pol_geom2 <- pol_geom + matrix(data = c(100, 50), ncol = 2)
st_coordinates(pol_geom3)
        X    Y L1 L2
[1,] 1100 1050  1  1
[2,] 1100 2050  1  1
[3,] 2100 2050  1  1
[4,] 1100 1050  1  1
[5,]  600  550  2  1
[6,]  600  150  2  1
[7,] 1100 1050  2  1
[8,]  600  550  2  1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, just multiply earlier in the polygon construction;

```
library(sf)
p <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(1000,1000), c(1000,2000), 
                c(2000,2000), c(1000,1000)), 
                rbind(c(500,500), c(500,100), 
                c(1000,1000), c(500,500))))  
p.shift <- st_sfc(p * c(2,3))
```

If you want to do this on more complex data you could muck directly with the node coordinates and then put everything back together. I am sure that there are more elegant ways to operate on the coordinate geometry and to take a tidy approach. I am loosely basing this code on what was done in the `st_jitter` function.

Here we add some example data. Note that I project it to state plane so that your specific scaling factors make a bit more sense. I also explode the MULTIPOLYGON geometry.

```
library(sf)
p <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
  p <- st_transform(p, 32119) #state plane meters
    p <- st_cast(p, "POLYGON")
```

Now, write a function that will take a single feature, scale the node coordinates and output the resulting feature.

```
f <- function(z, xscale=2, yscale=3) { 
       np <- st_polygon(list(st_coordinates(z)[,1:2]))
         cbind(st_as_sf(st_sfc(np * c(xscale,yscale)),crs = st_crs(p)),z)
  }
```

Here we create an empty sf object to store the results then apply a for loop to process the features. I am applying an equal scaling factor in both the x,y that will simple increase the size of the feature(s) proportionally. The default in the f function is 2,3.

```
shift <- st_sf(st_sfc(),crs = st_crs(p))              
  for(i in 1:nrow(p)) {
    shift <- rbind( shift, f(p[i,], 1.5, 1.5))
  }
```

Plot the results. Note that applying a scaling factor to coordinates in this way distorts the resulting features quite a bit.

```
plot(st_geometry(shift))
  plot(st_geometry(p), add=TRUE,
       col = '#ff8888')
```

Here is an approach where the feature node coordinates are jittered by some defined factor.

```
plot(st_geometry(p))
  plot(st_jitter(st_geometry(p), factor = .01), 
       add = TRUE, col = '#ff8888')
```

Comment: and how can I accomplish this with a polygon that I have not constructed myself (e.g. an imported shapefile)?

Comment: @kalakaru please see my updated answer.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just had to adapt the function a bit: f <- function(z, xscale=2, yscale=3) { 
  geo_sfg <- st_polygon(list(st_coordinates(z)[,1:2]))
  geo_sfc <- st_sfc(st_sfc(geo_sfg * c(xscale,yscale)),crs = st_crs(p))
  geo_sf <- st_sf(z %>% st_drop_geometry(),geometry = geo_sfc)
}